# How to specialize template type of a generic class in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible to specialize the template type of a generic class in a generic function in `typescript`?

Suppose I have a generic interface and a function which takes the interface constructor as argument:

```
interface IA<T> {
    func(arg: T)
}

function g<T, IAType extends IA<T>>(
    constructor: { new(): IAType }
): (arg: T) => IAType {
    const ins = new constructor();
    return arg => {
        ins.func(arg);
        return ins;
    }
}
```

then I provide the class implements `IA<T>`, which is

```
class A implements IA<{ key: string }> {
    func(arg: { key: string }) {
        console.log(arg.key);
    }
}

const t = g(A); // type of t is (arg: {}) => A
```

How can I write the function `g` or the class `A` so that function `g` can specialize the correct template type due to the argument pass in? I want to the final `t` has the type `(arg: {key: string}) => A`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type for `constructor` parameter for `g`

```
 constructor: { new(): IAType }
```

does not really impose a constraint that `func()` in `IAType` must have `T` as its argument type. The only constraint is `IAType extends IA<T>`, which means that `func` in `IAType` is allowed to have any type as long as it's compatible with `func(arg: T)`. The inference algorithm probably starts with minimal type which is `{}`, verifies that `func(arg: {})` is compatible with `func(arg: T)` and just stops there.

Being more strict about `constructor` type helps:

```
interface IA<T> {
    func(arg: T): void
}

function g<T, IAType extends IA<T>>(
    constructor: { new(): IA<T> & IAType }
): (arg: T) => IAType {
    const ins = new constructor();
    return arg => {
        ins.func(arg);
        return ins;
    }
}

class A implements IA<{ key: string }> {
    func(arg: { key: string }) {
        console.log(arg.key);
    }
}

const t = g(A); // type of t is (arg: { key: string; }) => A
```

Both `IA<T> & IAType` are necessary. If you have only `IA<T>`, `arg` type will be inferred as desired, but the return type would be only `IA<T>`, not `A`.